# How to stop invalid records showing in a filtered lookup

Tags: lookup

I have a custom object with a parent / child relationship to the account standard object.

On the custom object I also need to be able to record the relevant contact.  I have added a lookup to the contact record and selected a filter of:

> Contact: Account Name IDequals TestCustomObject: Account ID

This works in a way in that, when I select an invalid contact from the list it won't let me save the new custom object, however I want the lookup list to solely show contacts for the relative account - I don't want other contacts appearing in the list at all.

Does anyone know how to stop the invalid contacts from appearing?

As an aside is there any way to select more than one contact like a multi pick list?

Thanks for your help

Comment: As for selecting more than one contact; that is not possible as such. You'd need to either create multiple lookups or create a junction object to link multiple Contacts to multiple TestCustomObject records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry - I've been a bit reticent in updating my question.

I raised the issue on the Success community and opened a case - turns out it's a bug with the SF1 API which they're looking to fix in the future.

Not sure if this just affects iOS or not.

Thanks for the help though.

Regards,

Tim

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, would you please share the URL to your success community issue? Thanks

Comment: This is indeed a known issue, https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3uIAAS

Comment: Hi Doug, the URL was https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hYrmAAE, no progress on this limitation that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the correct filter, it will not only check on saving but also filter out non-matching records in the lookup.

So that probably means your filter is wrong. It appears you are comparing Account Name with AccountId. Try matching Account Id with Account Id and see if that works better.

Comment: Hi guy, Thanks for the answer, however the fields are correct for the lookup. I have checked and the filter is working fine on the desktop instance - only contacts relating to the account are showing.  On SF1 I think it might be showing a list of recent contacts rather than using the filter.

Comment: Having trouble replicating this, as I have Android 4.1 so not SF1. I didn't see a bug like this reported anywhere but you might want to create a Case with SF suppor..