# How to have lookup field on a Salesforce1 Publisher Action only display records that match the lookup filter?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lookup, lookup-filter, publisher-action

I'm having trouble in Salesforce1 with a lookup field on a Chatter Publisher Action **not** respecting the lookup field's required filter criteria.

When users are in the **Salesforce1** app (iOS or HTML5) and try to select a value for the lookup field, they see ALL records listed rather than just the records that meet the lookup filter's criteria.

The only viable workaround I can think of is writing a completely custom visualforce page and controller where I explicitly build the HTML select field and options, but that is extreme overkill and I lose out on the whole declarative point-n-click development...

This issue *might* be related to this other post, [How to stop invalid records showing in a filtered lookup](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/how-to-stop-invalid-records-showing-in-a-filtered-lookup), but the post and answer wasn't clear enough for me to tell for sure.

Thanks for any guidance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered this is indeed a known issue with Salesforce, https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3uIAAS

[image]